# How to save/load the scene of a checkpoint in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm coding a top-down 2D Unity game. There is a room (separate scene) with an enemy and a checkpoint inside. I have tried to make it so that I can go to the checkpoint, have it log my location and current scene, and then die to the enemy and respawn in the same room. The checkpoint sets the correct variable, however, when I die to the enemy and switch scenes to the death screen, the saved scene variable goes back to null.

The short version - Unity isn't saving a variable between scenes.

I have tried putting the player (who has a saved scene variable) in DontDestroyOnLoad to see if it just wasn't saving the player between scenes, but that did not work. I have also tried creating a static variable to save the checkpoint scene in, but it was very confusing and I'm not sure if I got everything right.

Static Code (this is in its own script)

```cs
public class SaveScene
{
    public static Scene SavedScene { get; set; }
}
```

*Again, I don't know if I did this part right so any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Checkpoint Script

```cs
public class Checkpoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.transform.tag == "Player")
        {
            SaveScene.SavedScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene(); //calls to static 
            PlayerMovement.lastCheckPointPos = transform.position; //saves the location for player
        }
    }
}
```

*This part works correctly to save the scene once I hit the checkpoint, but does not save over between scenes.*

I've been stuck on this for a while and it's preventing the game from moving forward in progress so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use PlayerPrefs and save the build index or scene name there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did the correct thing about saving your data in a non-scene-related place (script with the object marked as DontDestroyOnLoad in your case, however, it is not the only option) to prevent your storage from being destroyed while loading new scenes.

Now, you have to determine WHAT you need to save. When the scene is unloaded, your variable pointing to it will become not correct. So saving the `Scene` is not an option. You can use both index or scene name to be used later in `LoadScene` call. It should work.

So, you are on the right way. Just need to correct your current situation a little bit.